# Using gmaps4rails with backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to get gmaps4rails to work with my backbone views and templates.

As a quick introduction, I'm trying to make a page for events, which when viewed for each individual event has a Google Map with the location shown amongst other things. However I'm not quite sure how to tie it all together.

The steps I have taken are as follows:
Gemfile:

```
gem 'gmaps4rails'
```

I then ran `rails generate gmaps4rails:install` and added the following to `application.js`:

```
// GOOGLE MAPS
//= require_directory ./gmaps4rails
```

I then modified my model and migrations as so:

Model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_gmappable
   ...
   def gmaps4rails_address
      self.location
   end
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateEventGmaps < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :events, :latitude,  :float
    add_column :events, :longitude, :float
    add_column :events, :gmaps, :boolean 
  end
end
```

I then ran `rake db:migrate` and seeded my database with `rake db:seed`. Each event has a location set to some arbitrary place, and I do not get any errors when seeding.

For the next bit I'm not quite sure how to tie it all together with my controller and backbone views and so far I've added the following code:
Events Controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @json = @event.to_gmaps4rails
    respond_with @event
  end
```

Backbone view:

```
class CPP.Views.Events.Edit extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['backbone/templates/events/view']

  initialize: ->
    @render()

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(event: @model))
    @
```

Template:

```
  <div class="span6" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">
        <h1 class="section-header"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> Location</h1>
        <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
      </div>
      <div class="span6">
        <div class="event-location">
          <dl>
            <dt>Address</dt>
            <dd><%= @event.get 'location' %></dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

However I'm getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: gmaps4rails is not defined` Javascript error.
I had a read of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472293/backbone-js-and-gmaps4rails-maps-initialization?rq=1) which suggests that perhaps you can't do this in the Backbone views?

I was just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction! It'd be really nice to be able to show Google maps on my page.

Thanks.

Comment: sounds odd: there is no js variable named `gmaps4rails` in the gem

Comment: It's from the lin <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>, which I can only think is meant to be used in your Rails View? as defined in the Quick start:
https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Comment: Yes, but this is Ruby, not javascript. Javascript error is non sense

Comment: My templates and views are in CoffeeScript because I'm using backbone.js MVC rather than Ruby Views. I don't actually have a Ruby View for Events

Comment: sure but `<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>` is still Ruby... could yo post the resulting html?